# Font awesome loaded,but is not working on Internet explorer 11?

Tags: css, angular, internet-explorer-11, font-awesome, microsoft-edge

Font Awesome icons are rendering properly in Internet Explorer 10 but not in IE 11.

Below is the Player-status.component.html (using as modal page) , taking div>id>status as  html element this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#status').

you can refer in player-status.component.ts.Instead of id(#status) if i take window object then font awesome is working correctly but the sad other functionalities are breaking.

All these functinalities are working chrome,firefox,IE 10 but not in IE 11.But IE 11 somehow it is blocking to execute this font awesome class ->fixed-action-btn horizontal click-to-toggle.

I have gone through all those IE related issue with font awesome but nothing seems to work. I have already spent 2 days on this. If anybody has encountered this kind of issue please help.

#### Player-status.component.html

```
<div materialize="modal" [materializeActions]="modalActions" [materializeParams]="[{dismissible: true}]" id="status" class="modal bottom-sheet iscroll-wrapper"
  iscroll>
  <div class="modal-content iscr`enter code here`oll-scroller">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s4">
        <h5 class="app-colour">Question Status <span class="new badge blue" data-badge-caption="">Filter | {{getFilterSetting()}}</span></h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col s8">
        <div class="fixed-action-btn horizontal click-to-toggle">
          <a class="app btn-floating btn-large app-background-colour custom-btn ">
            <i class="fa fa-filter white-text" ></i>
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li class="tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Marked For Review"><a class="btn-floating app-background-colour custom-btn" (click)="setQuestionSelection('1')"><i
              class="fa fa-bookmark white-text"></i></a></li>
            <li class="tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Answered"><a class="btn-floating app-background-colour custom-btn" (click)="setQuestionSelection('2')"><i
              class="fa fa-check-square-o white-text"></i></a></li>
            <li class="tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Not Answered"><a class="btn-floating app-background-colour custom-btn" (click)="setQuestionSelection('3')"><i
              class="fa fa-square-o white-text"></i></a></li>
            <li class="tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Show All"><a class="btn-floating app-background-colour custom-btn" (click)="setQuestionSelection('0')"><i
              class="material-icons white-text">subject</i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="collection">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let question of qpService.items | customFilter: questionSelection let i = index;">

        <li class="collection-item avatar">
          <div *ngIf="question?.length > 0">"No matches"</div>


          <div *ngIf="!question.isMultipleInteraction">
            <i class="material-icons circle blue grey lighten-2" >check_circle</i>
            <span class="title black-text" >Question {{ question.slNo }}</span>

            <div>
              <div class="question-detail" [innerHTML]="question.title | sanitizeHtml">
              </div>
            </div>


            <p class="blue-grey-text" *ngIf="question.status.answered">
              <span class="grey-text">Your answer:</span> <span [innerHTML]="(question.answers[question.status.selectedAnswer]?.title)|sanitizeHtml"></span>
            </p>
            <p class="grey-text" [hidden]="question.status.answered">Not yet answered</p>
            <span class="secondary-content hide" [hidden]="!question.status.answered"><i class="material-icons green-text" [ngClass]="{'green-text': question.status.wasCorrect, 'red-text': !question.status.wasCorrect}">{{ question.status.wasCorrect ? 'check': 'close' }}</i></span>


          </div>
          <div *ngIf="question.isMultipleInteraction">
            <i class="material-icons circle blue grey lighten-2" >check_circle</i>
            <span class="title black-text" >Question {{ question.slNo }}</span>

            <div>
              <div class="question-detail" [innerHTML]="question.qMainBody | sanitizeHtml">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" *ngFor="let childQuestion of question.playerItemChild; let j = index">
              <i class="material-icons circle blue grey lighten-2" [hidden]="question.status.answered">check_circle</i>
              <span class="title black-text" [hidden]="question.status.answered">Question {{ question.slNo }}.{{childQuestion.slNo}}</span>

              <div>
                <div class="question-detail" [innerHTML]="childQuestion.title | sanitizeHtml">
                </div>
              </div>


              <p class="blue-grey-text" *ngIf="childQuestion.status.answered">
                <span class="grey-text">Your answer:</span> <span [innerHTML]="childQuestion.answers[childQuestion.status.selectedAnswer]?.title | sanitizeHtml"></span>
              </p>
              <p class="grey-text" [hidden]="childQuestion.status.answered">Not yet answered</p>
              <span class="secondary-content hide" [hidden]="!childQuestion.status.answered"><i class="material-icons green-text" [ngClass]="{'green-text': childQuestion.status.wasCorrect, 'red-text': !childQuestion.status.wasCorrect}">{{ childQuestion.status.wasCorrect ? 'check': 'close' }}</i></span>


            </div>

          </div>
        </li>

      </ng-container>

    </ul>
    <ul class="collection" *ngIf="(qpService.items | customFilter: questionSelection).length < 1"> 
      <li class="collection-item avatar">        
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle circle"></i>
        <span class="title black-text">Questions not found.</span>
        <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"></a>
      </li>

    </ul>

    <div class="spacing">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="done-button modal-footer">
    <span class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" (click)="closeModal()">Done</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Player-status-component.ts

```
import { AfterContentInit, Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, OnDestroy, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterializeAction } from 'angular2-materialize';

import { QPService } from './../services/qp.service';
import { Unsubscriber } from './../../../shared/unsubscriber';
import { CustomFilter } from './customFilter';
import { QuestionOptions, QUESTIONS_VALUES } from "./question_status_options";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { SanitizeHtmlPipe } from './../card/SanitizeHtmlPipe';
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';


declare var IScroll: any;
declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-player-status',
  templateUrl: './player-status.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player-status.component.css'],
  providers: [CustomFilter]
})
export class PlayerStatusComponent extends Unsubscriber implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  @Output() public modalActions = new EventEmitter<string | MaterializeAction>();


  private _players: any = [];
  private _modal: HTMLElement = null;
  // private _modal1: HTMLElement = null;
  private _scroll = null;
  public questions: Observable<any[]>;
  private _questionSelection: any;


  public statuses: QuestionOptions[] = QUESTIONS_VALUES;

  constructor(private _qpservice: QPService, private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
    super();

    this._questionSelection = "0";
  }



  get questionSelection() {
    return this._questionSelection;
  }

  set questionSelection(value) {

    this._questionSelection = value;
  }

  public setQuestionSelection(value) {
    this.questionSelection = value;
    this.refreshScroll();
  }

  public getFilterSetting() {
    // console.log("I am here");
    let value = "";
    if (this.questionSelection === '0') {
      value = " None ";
    }
    else if (this.questionSelection === '1') {
      value = " Marked For Review ";
    }
    else if (this.questionSelection === '2') {

      value = " Answered ";
    }
    else if (this.questionSelection === '3') {
      value = " Not Answered ";
    }

    return value;
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._modal = this._elementRef
      .nativeElement
      .querySelector('#status');
      // this._modal1=this._elementRef
      // .nativeElement
      // .querySelector(window);// This is rendering well and working with font awesome classes on internet explorer 11

      (function () {
        function handleMouseWheel(e)
        {
        if (!e) e = this._modal.event;

        if (this._modal.addEventListener) {
          // console.log("I am here");
          this._modal.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", handleMouseWheel, false); }
          else { document.onmousewheel = handleMouseWheel; }
        }
    })();
    this._scroll = new IScroll(this._modal, {
      deceleration: 0.01,     
      mouseWheel: true,
      mouseWheelSpeed: 30,
      resizePolling:60,
      probeType: 2,
      freeScroll:true,
      scrollbars: true,
      interactiveScrollbars:true,
      // scrollX: true,
      scrollY: true,
      tap: false,
      click: true
    });

    let onActivateQuestion = this._qpservice
      .onActivateQuestion
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.refreshScroll();
      });

    this.disposal.push(onActivateQuestion);
    //this.disposal.push(onCompleted);
  }

  public refreshScroll() {

    this._modal.style.display = 'initial';
    //console.log("--refreshScroll");
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._modal.style.display = 'hidden';
      this._scroll.refresh();
    });
  }


  public openModal() {
    this.modalActions.emit({ action: 'modal', params: ['open'] });
  }

  public closeModal() {
    this.modalActions.emit({ action: 'modal', params: ['close'] });
  }

  get qpService() {
    return this._qpservice;
  }

}
```

#### player-status.component.css

```
:host {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal {
  overflow-y: auto;

}

.modal-content {
  z-index: 5003;
}

.modal.bottom-sheet {
  max-height: 100%;
}

@media (min-height: 739px) {
  div.modal.bottom-sheet {
    max-height: 60%;
  }
}

.modal.bottom-sheet .modal-footer {
  display: initial;
}

.modal.bottom-sheet.open .modal-footer {
  display: initial;
}

audio {
  display: none;
}

.play-button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.done-button {
  z-index: 9003;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(96, 125, 139, 0.45);
}

.collection .collection-item.avatar {
  min-height: 65px;
}

.custom-btn{
  box-shadow:none;

}

.app-background-colour:hover{
background-color: #D67F45;
}

.fixed-action-btn {  
  position: absolute;
  right: 23px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  bottom:auto;
  z-index: 998;
  display: block;
}
.spacing {
  padding: 4px 6px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

span.badge{
  float: none;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

### Expected Result

[image]

### Actual result

[image]

Comment: You need to turn on debugging in the browser dev tool to break on exceptions. f12>Debug tab, select "Break on all exceptions" from the dropdown (it looks like a stop sign), then (without closing the dev tool (PIN it to your browser) return to the page you are debugging. The browser will now break when it encounters a scripting error. To debug blocked content, markup and security issues fist go Tools>Internet Options>Advance tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes. The Console tab of the dev tool will now list errors when you fist open the dev tool.